# Are all symmetric idempotent Latin squares known?

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, classification, latin-square

Are all symmetric idempotent Latin squares known?

There is such a square of order $n$ if and only if $n$ is odd. However, is there a classification of all of them?

(The motivation for the question is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/151397/22051), Latin squares and quasigroups being the same thing).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe these papers will be of interest for you:

[J. Dudek, On Steiner quasigroups](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136439/MathSlov_37-1987-1_9.pdf)

Galuszka_A characterization of commutative and associative groupoids. Discusiones Math., Algebra and Stoch. Methods, 15(1995), 121--125.